# Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)

Tags: email, ldap, dovecot

I'm hoping I can use some help.

I'm configuring dovecot_ldap, but I can't seem to be able to get dovecot to authenticate the ldap user.

Below is my config and log info:

```
hosts = 192.168.128.45:3268
dn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=company,dc=example,dc=com
dnpass = "passwd"
auth_bind = yes
ldap_version = 3
base = dc=company, dc=example, dc=com
user_attrs = sAMAccountName=home=/var/vmail/example.com/%$,uid=1001,gid=1001
user_filter = (&(sAMAccountName=%Ln))
pass_filter = (&(ObjectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=%u))
```

### dovecot.conf

```
# 2.0.19: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.2.0-33-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_realms = example.com
auth_verbose = yes
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_access_groups = mail
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  driver = passwd
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
passdb {
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext
  driver = ldap
}
userdb {
  args = username_format=%u /etc/dovecot/users
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocol imap {
  imap_client_workarounds = tb-extra-mailbox-sep
  imap_logout_format = bytes=%i/%o
  mail_plugins =
}
```

### mail.log

```
Nov 29 10:51:44 mail dovecot: auth-worker: pam(charyorde,10.10.1.28): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Nov 29 10:51:44 mail dovecot: auth-worker: passwd(charyorde,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:44 mail dovecot: auth: passwd(charyorde,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:44 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<charyorde>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.10.1.28, lip=10.10.1.30, mpid=1892, TLS
Nov 29 10:51:44 mail dovecot: imap(charyorde): Error: user charyorde: Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)
Nov 29 10:51:44 mail dovecot: imap(charyorde): Error: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
Nov 29 10:51:46 mail dovecot: auth-worker: pam(charyorde,10.10.1.28): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Nov 29 10:51:46 mail dovecot: auth-worker: passwd(charyorde,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:46 mail dovecot: auth: passwd(charyorde,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:46 mail dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<charyorde>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.10.1.28, lip=10.10.1.30, mpid=1894, TLS
Nov 29 10:51:46 mail dovecot: imap(charyorde): Error: user charyorde: Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)
Nov 29 10:51:46 mail dovecot: imap(charyorde): Error: Internal error occurred. Refer to server log for more information.
Nov 29 10:51:48 mail dovecot: auth-worker: pam(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Nov 29 10:51:48 mail dovecot: auth-worker: passwd(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:48 mail dovecot: auth: ldap(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:48 mail dovecot: auth: passwd-file(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1880]: idle timeout -- exiting
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1879]: idle timeout -- exiting
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1886]: proxymap stream disconnect
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1887]: proxymap stream disconnect
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1886]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1887]: auto_clnt_close: disconnect private/tlsmgr stream
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1887]: idle timeout -- exiting
Nov 29 10:51:54 mail postfix/smtpd[1886]: idle timeout -- exiting
Nov 29 10:51:56 mail dovecot: auth-worker: pam(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Nov 29 10:51:56 mail dovecot: auth-worker: passwd(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:56 mail dovecot: auth: ldap(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:51:56 mail dovecot: auth: passwd-file(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:52:04 mail dovecot: auth-worker: pam(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Nov 29 10:52:04 mail dovecot: auth-worker: passwd(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:52:04 mail dovecot: auth: ldap(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:52:04 mail dovecot: auth: passwd-file(charyorde@example.com,10.10.1.28): unknown user
Nov 29 10:52:06 mail dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 3 attempts): user=<charyorde@example.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=10.10.1.28, lip=10.10.1.30, TLS
```

Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Well, so what *is* `mail_uid` set to, and what does that value map to?

Comment: Probably I don't know where to set that. I know that `/var/vmail/` uid and gid is set to 1001. I don't know what setting `mail_uid` means.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. i think I need to set `first_valid_uid` and `first_valid_gid` in dovecot.conf and also add `virtual_uid_maps` and `virtual_gid_maps` in postfix.conf. I'll post back if this works. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Sorry. That was a stupid response from me. If authenticating via ldap, do I still need `mail_uid`. At the moment `mail_uid` is not set. And I'm not expecting dovecot to use it. I'm expecting it to use ldap.

Comment: Well, the error message specifically refers to `mail_uid`, so whether you expect dovecot to use it or not, it obviously wants something.

Comment: I added `mail_uid = 1001` and `mail_gid = 1001`. The specific error `Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)` now seem to go away. But i still can't authenticate. Dovecot still returns unknown user for the ldap user.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need dovecot to know anything special about your users beyond the meta data of a normal unix system user (i.e. home dir, gid, etc), then it is much simpler to configure dovecot to do pam authentication and use pam to communicate with ldap.

Your `dovecot.conf` would look something like this:

```
passdb {
        driver = pam
        args = %s
}
userdb {
        driver = passwd
}
```

Then you have to put something in `/etc/pam.d/dovecot`. If you are already using LDAP athentication for your system users, you can probably just include the appropriate context like so:

```
auth      include   system-remote-login
password  include   system-remote-login
```

On the other hand if you have not setup pam_ldap to authenticate your users on the system, you probably need a custom scheme that does just that:

```
auth      sufficient pam_ldap.so     minimum_uid=1000
auth      required   pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
auth      required   pam_env.so
password  sufficient pam_ldap.so     minimum_uid=1000
password  required   pam_unix.so     try_first_pass nullok
```

And you'll need to tell your system NSS how to talk to ldap, usually via `/etc/nslcd.conf` and something like the following:

```
uri ldap://localhost/
base dc=example,dc=com
base   group  ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
base   passwd ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
base   shadow ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
nss_min_uid 1000
```

Incidentally, if you leave out the `userdb { driver = password }` bit from the `dovecot.conf` file, you will get the same error you were getting from dovecot's LDAP lookup.